# usage of querySourceFeatures and setData

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I'm developping a map using mapbox gl js, my issue is the following:

- I have 1 source and I apply 1 setData on this source with a geojson collection of points -> fine
- I want to update one position for one feature (point) of this featurecollection
- I do querySourceFeatures and I get an array of features -> fine
- I detect the feature I want to modify and I modify the lat-long accordingly -> fine
- I would like to apply the whole setData with the modify feature to redraw but ...
- Here is the problem, how do I go from the array of features (one is modified) to a feature collection compatible with setData ... ?

I'm confused why (or what) there is not a straight path to do that ... What do I miss here?

can you help me please?

thanks,

Olivier

Answer (score -1):

finally, I rebuild the featureCollection "manually" in a separate function ... I though it would not be an optimized solution but at the end, reveals quite straight ...

```
function build_featureCollection_from_array(parray) {
    lv_fc = {};
    lv_fc.type = "FeatureCollection";
    lv_fc.features = parray;
    return lv_fc;
}
```